# Confusion about tangent space of a surface $T_pS$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider the regular surface created by the coordinate patch $$f(u,v)=(u,v,u^{2}+v^{2})$$ and the curve $$C(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,1).$$
$C$ is in the surface $S$ so it’s derivative i.e. $C’(t)=(-\sin t,\cos t,0)$ must lie in the $T_{p}S$ at every point $P$ in $S$ generated by $\{f_u, f_v\}$ but apparently $C’(t)$ isn't generated by the basis $\{(1,0,2u),(0,1,2v\} $.

Comment: what mean "$c'(t)$ int generated by the basis..." ?

Comment: @Surb I mean I can't write it in the bases coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$C(t)=f(\cos(t),\sin(t)),$$
then $$C'(t)=-\sin(t)\cdot f_u(\cos(t),\sin(t))+\cos(t)\cdot f_v(\cos(t),\sin(t))\in T_{(\cos(t),\sin(t))}S.$$

Comment: Concretely, note that $$(-\sin t,\cos t,0) = (-\sin t)(1,0,2\cos t) + (\cos t)(0,1,2\sin t).$$